# Chrome storage sync / local solution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm dealing with a dilemma regarding chrome storage.

My use case it that I have a Chrome extension that will store the user's cleaned tabs on a daily basis. One of the requirements is that a history is kept, so I store tabs in an array per day.

My current implementation is to store to `chrome.storage.sync`, however this storage is way to small for what I intend to use it. It is in fact, rather tiny.

The second option would be to use `chrome.storage.local` which has sufficient capacity, but we don't want the user's historical tab data to get lost, so this poses the problem that we actually need sync.

The third option is to use localstorage and implement a custom sync to some free remote service like Firebase.

My question is:
Is my understanding right that `chrome.storage.sync` is only to be used for some configuration data? And is there a straightforward way to force sync the 'local' chrome storage anyhow (might Firebase be an option)?

Comment: The sync storage is for configs, yes. You can use any other storage (like local, localStorage, or IndexedDB) with any custom external cloud sync API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my understanding right that chrome.storage.sync is only to be used for some configuration data?

Yes, being a limited storage, it is intended for maintaining different forms of state data.

> And is there a straightforward way to force sync the 'local' chrome
>   storage anyhow (might Firebase be an option)?

You can definitely use some external service like Firebase to save the user data and gain synchronization on different devices